# Spring AOP. Getting the bean name from the JoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration. I want to get the bean name from the JoinPoint if is possible....

```
@Aspect
public class TDKAspectLogger {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Before(“execution(void set*(*))”)
    public void logInfo(JoinPoint point) {
          logger.info(“changing bean -> ” );
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not a Spring user, so I do not know much about Spring beans. But if it would be satisfactory to get the class name, I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Stream.of(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotationsByType(Service.class))
      .forEach(q -> logger.info(q.value()));
```

to get the bean as declared by `@Service` annotation.

However, not all beans are created this way. Some are created by `@Bean` annotated methods, some can even be added manually to the the context. So, if you annotate your bean classes with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Qualifier` etc. and use `@ComponentScan` you might get what you want. You just need to remember that it's not the universal way to retrieve all beans currently available in the context (it will not work for classes without any annotations/metadata).